# Alternative "Not Equal" sign in Dart

Tags: android-studio, dart

I was looking into some dart package code (jwt_decode package) when I ran into this fancy "not-equal" symbol:

[image: Neat not-equal sign]

(See the "Not Equal" character(s) in the -if- clause?)

It looks like Dart understands it. Also, when I try to select it, it is selected as two characters:

[image: Two-character unequal sign]

I think this has better readability than the classic != signs. Is there any key combination to generate this symbol?

Comment: It might be just your IDE rendering the !=  symbols together in a fancy way. If you open the file in a basic file editor how does it look?

Comment: @RobCo Yeah, it shows as  !=  in the text editor. So how come the IDE doesn't do the same with my own not-equal signs?

Comment: @RobCo Im concluding each package brings its own IDE settings/preferences with it! Other files in my project are not behaving similarly.